# Scraping data from ESRI ArcGIS web map

Tags: data, web-mapping

I am trying to scrape all school boundaries from [this website](https://tcdsb.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=8343c3d733954bd8879419677fa7c71c).  I want to download them in any geo-format, such as `.geojson`, `.kml`, or `.shp`

I figured out that the school boundaries are [rendered as `<path>` attributes](https://i.gyazo.com/7fc44e66befff77535a475087f5bf649.jpg).  Looking in the [source code](http://view-source:https://tcdsb.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=8343c3d733954bd8879419677fa7c71c) didn't help.

Does anyone have experience scraping ArcGIS websites, that can give me some hints on how to scrape this ste?

Comment: Morally, I feel weird about answering questions about how to "scrap" data. That data is public and can be accessed, but do the data owners want you to do that? I dont know. Anyways, my comfort level starts and stops at pointing you in the right direction: https://services3.arcgis.com/i9SIJZvRhal6cvaG/arcgis/rest/services/FINAL201819FAB/FeatureServer/0/  - nothing more.

Comment: web maps are pictures of data for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ogr2ogr works great with ESRI REST give it url

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON Route66.json "http://imgis.nps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/NHT/NHT/MapServer/9/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON -gt 1000

Read the result of a FeatureService request against a GeoServices REST server:

ogrinfo -ro -al "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/FeatureServer/0/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json"

Comment: It's not clear from the question that feature services are enabled. If they aren't, then this solution won't work. It's probably best to caveat your answer.

Comment: nice answer, i have never done this.